# Password reset with Piranha CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, piranha-cms

Using the **Piranha CMS** platform on ASP.NET Core, what is the best way for the users to chose their own password? Using the management interface, I can create new users and assign them roles, but as part of the process I need to chose a password for them.

Not an issue as such, if the user can then reset his password (either on first login or from link received via email) but I've not found the way to configure such features. Do such feature exist?

If not, I don't mind creating a custom page/action/view, if someone can help me with the backend code. i.e. what classes and methods should I be using to access the user repository and update passwords?

Comment: Under the hood, Piranha is using Microsoft Identity for authentication and authorization.  There's a bit to it, but the short answer is that you will want to use the identity services to perform the password reset.  A common approach is to provide the user a reset token via email or SMS, then use the reset token and reset the password. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp.net-identity%5D+reset